# Update rows with where condition from selecting rows with another condition in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I m stuck with a particular query, it is tricky but I m unable to resolve it.

Here I have a table questions with many rows and its column(id, subject_id, topic_id, description, pic, cha, pica, chb, picb, chc, picc, chd, picd, answer, attempt, correct, level, checked, BookId, PageNumber)

Now I want to update table questions where topic_id is lm and the value to be inserted is from getting the value from same table questions where topic_id is newton

I tried the 3 queries but it is not working:

1.>

```
UPDATE questions
SET
id = newdata.id,
subject_id = newdata.subject_id,
topic_id = newdata.topic_id,
description = newdata.description,
pic = newdata.pic,
cha = newdata.cha,
pica = newdata.pica,
chb = newdata.chb,
picb = newdata.picb,
chc = newdata.chc,
picc = newdata.picc,
chd = newdata.chd,
picd = newdata.picd,
answer = newdata.answer,
attempt = newdata.attempt,
correct = newdata.correct,
level = newdata.level,
checked = newdata.checked,
BookId = newdata.BookId,
PageNumber = newdata.PageNumber
FROM
(SELECT * FROM questions WHERE topic_id = 'newton') newdata
WHERE
topic_id = 'lm'
AND topic_id = newdata.topic_id;
```

2.>

```
UPDATE questions
SET
id = newdata.id,
subject_id = newdata.subject_id,
topic_id = newdata.topic_id,
description = newdata.description,
pic = newdata.pic,
cha = newdata.cha,
pica = newdata.pica,
chb = newdata.chb,
picb = newdata.picb,
chc = newdata.chc,
picc = newdata.picc,
chd = newdata.chd,
picd = newdata.picd,
answer = newdata.answer,
attempt = newdata.attempt,
correct = newdata.correct,
level = newdata.level,
checked = newdata.checked,
BookId = newdata.BookId,
PageNumber = newdata.PageNumber
from questions newdata
WHERE
questions.topic_id = 'lm'
AND newdata.topic_id = 'newton';
```

3.>

```
UPDATE questions
SET
id = (SELECT id FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
subject_id = (SELECT subject_id FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
topic_id = (SELECT topic_id FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
description = (SELECT description FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
pic = (SELECT pic FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
cha = (SELECT cha FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
pica = (SELECT pica FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
chb = (SELECT chb FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
picb = (SELECT picb FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
chc = (SELECT chc FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
picc = (SELECT picc FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
chd = (SELECT chd FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
picd = (SELECT picd FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
answer = (SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
attempt = (SELECT attempt FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
correct = (SELECT correct FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
level = (SELECT level FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
checked = (SELECT checked FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
BookId = (SELECT BookId FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton'),
PageNumber = (SELECT PageNumber FROM questions WHERE topid_id = 'newton')
WHERE topic_id = 'lm';
```

None of these are working.

Please help me out.

Apologies if I did any simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you cannot reference the same table in an update, unless you use a `join` or overly nested subqueries.  Your queries would probably work if you use the proper syntax for MySQL, though.  The first would be:

```
UPDATE questions q JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE topic_id = 'newton') newdata
       ON q.topic_id = newdata.topic_id
    SET q.id = newdata.id,
        q.subject_id = newdata.subject_id,
        q.topic_id = newdata.topic_id,
        q.description = newdata.description,
        q.pic = newdata.pic,
        q.cha = newdata.cha,
        q.pica = newdata.pica,
        q.chb = newdata.chb,
        q.picb = newdata.picb,
        q.chc = newdata.chc,
        q.picc = newdata.picc,
        q.chd = newdata.chd,
        q.picd = newdata.picd,
        q.answer = newdata.answer,
        q.attempt = newdata.attempt,
        q.correct = newdata.correct,
        q.level = newdata.level,
        q.checked = newdata.checked,
        q.BookId = newdata.BookId,
        q.PageNumber = newdata.PageNumber
WHERE q.topic_id = 'lm';
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff its not working. 0 records are affected.

Comment: @Atiq . . . I cannot account for your data or the logic being used, only the syntax of the statement.  Clearly, there are no matches.  You should fix the conditions so they are correct for your data.